# While Installing Jetstream. Having these route not found issues

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-jetstream, laravel-ui

> composer require laravel/jetstream

`````
PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
````Using version ^1.3 for laravel/jetstream````
````./composer.json has been updated````
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

   ErrorException

  >require(F:\WEB\Servers\xampp\htdocs\apps\laravel\v8\laravel-multi-auth\vendor\laravel\jetstream\src/../routes/.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory 

  >at F:\WEB\Servers\xampp\htdocs\apps\laravel\v8\laravel-multi-auth\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider.php:144
    140▕      */
    141▕     protected function loadRoutesFrom($path)
    142▕     {
    143▕         if (! ($this->app instanceof CachesRoutes && $this->app->routesAreCached())) {
  ➜ 144▕             require $path;
    145▕         }
    146▕     }
    147▕
    148▕     /**
`````

> 1   F:\WEB\Servers\xampp\htdocs\apps\laravel\v8\laravel-multi-auth\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider.php:144
> require()

> 2   F:\WEB\Servers\xampp\htdocs\apps\laravel\v8\laravel-multi-auth\vendor\laravel\jetstream\src\JetstreamServiceProvider.php:175

Whoops\Exception\ErrorException

Module 'openssl' already loaded

at Unknown:0
1▕

> 1   F:\WEB\Servers\xampp\htdocs\apps\laravel\v8\laravel-multi-auth\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Run.php:408
> Whoops\Run::handleError("Module 'openssl' already loaded", "Unknown")

> 2   [internal]:0
> Whoops\Run::handleShutdown()
> Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Comment: `in Unknown on line 0` is often a smell that something is really wrong, possibly out of memory errors, maybe incomplete downloads of libraries, maybe something else. Have you tried deleting your "vendor" folder and then installing Jetstream?